# The principal value of the following complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the principal value of the following complex exponential:

$$(i^i)^i = i^{-1} = -i 
$$
So principal value is $$ e^{-i\pi/2} = -i?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are worried about using $(z^a)^b = z^{ab}$, as you should be -- the formula is not valid for all choices of $z$, $a$ and $b$ -- you can always use the definitions: assuming the principal branch of $\log$ we get

$$i^i = \exp(i\log i) = \exp(-\frac\pi2)$$

and consequently

$$(i^i)^i = (\exp(-\frac\pi2))^i = \exp( i \log(\exp(-\frac\pi2))) = \exp(-\frac{i\pi}2) = -i.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Use Euler's formula.
$$e^{-i\pi/2} = \cos(-\pi/2) + i\sin(-\pi/2) = -i.$$

Comment: There are extra $i$'s in your formula.

Comment: i, i, cap'n. fixed. Thanks.